# Attachment API returning Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404 from Apex but works from Anonymous window & workbench

Tags: apex, community, rest-api, sobject, workbench

I am trying to access Attachment info using
`/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Attachment/\<attachment-id\>` which works fine from workbench.

It also works fine from Anonymous window using
`URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Attachment/\<attachment-id\>`.

However, when I am trying to run it from Apex class (called from Partner Portal LWC component), it always return Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404 in the response.

This is how I am setting the request.

```
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Attachment/\<attachment-id\>');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

Is there anything which I am doing in incorrect manner?

Comment: The session you establish via LWC doesn't have enough privileges to see the attachment or the attachment ID you're providing doesn't exist in this org. (Workbench could be connected to a different org)

Comment: @identigral - Workbench is connected to same org. We don't have multiple orgs. if it is issue with session privileges', how can I check that and fix it?